# How to prepend an element to a React element?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and am trying to make some modifications to a WordPress block.

If I do this:

```
const addContentTypeMarkup = ( element, blockType, attributes ) => {
    // Do nothing if it's another block than our defined ones.
    if ( ! enableBlockContentTypeAttribute.includes( blockType.name ) ) {
        return element;
    }
    if ( attributes.contenttitle) {
        return (
            <div className="test">
            {element}
            </div>
    )
    } else {
        return element;
    }
};
addFilter( 'blocks.getSaveElement', 'my-mods/add-content-type-markup', addContentTypeMarkup);
```

then all is fine. But I don't want to just return the element wrapped in a div. I just want to add content before the element. If I try:

```
return (
            <h3>test</h3>
            {element}
    )
```

Then I get compile error:

```
ERROR in ./js/block.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (149:12)

  147 |         return (
  148 |             <h3>test</h3>
> 149 |             {element}
      |             ^
  150 |     )
  151 |     } else {
  152 |         return element;
```

Being new to React I am sure I am overlooking some simple concept.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Fragment` instead, it **won't be rendered** and **will not** be added into the DOM tree.

```
return (
   <>
     <h3>test</h3>
     {element}
   </>
);
```

You can also use `React.Fragment` syntax:

```
return (
   <React.Fragment>
     <h3>test</h3>
     {element}
   </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, that works! But curious, how would I add my element as the first child element relative to first tag? So if originally it was <div><div>some content</div></div>, how to get <div><h3></h3><div>some content</div></div>?

Comment: @Brian Is that outer div inside your component or in e.g. parent component?

Comment: The outer div is the first container of the element that my function receives. So in the WordPress hook, I get element as <div><div>some content</div></div>. I am then trying to make my added content be the first child. Just when I got used to jQuery I started messing with React so I think I have some learning ahead of me to figure out the React way of DOM manipulation!

Comment: @Brian It's not that easy to manipulate over DOM in React, since React doesn't really depend on DOM, it has it's own Virtual DOM. It's kind of advanced to remove or inject html tags in specified part of the DOM programatically. The more you know about React, you will see what I mean

Comment: Ok, in my case it will actually work fine if my added content is before the element. So I guess I won't labor over it! regards, Brian

Comment: @Brian If you would have access to that first div, you could set it's id to some value and then get it with `getElementById` and then insert `element` into that using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but this is highly discouraged method

Comment: I know its class name in advance, and I add to it prior to my hook "has-contenttype-exercise". But I don't know the id in advance.

Comment: @Brian If you know it's classname then you re able to find it and store in a variable. However keep in mind that it's not secure, since harmful code can be executed inside

Answer (score 0):

You need a wrapper for these elements, you can use a div or the react Fragment component.

```
<div>
  <h3>test</h3>
  {element}
</div>
```

or

```
<React.Fragment>
  <h3>test</h3>
  {element}
</React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return JSX, it NEEDS to be wrapped in an element. Usually we use divs or spans, but if you don't want an actual element, you can use fragments instead. A fragment is a kind of "pseudo-element": it doesn't actually render an element to the DOM, but acts as a wrapper for returned JSX.

The long way to do this:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        {element}
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

The newer short syntax:

```
return (
    <>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        {element}
    </>
);
```